# tikz trees vertical space and "hanging" branches

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-trees

I'm trying to create a slide with beamer.  Here it is:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer} %
\usepackage{tikz} %
\usetikzlibrary{trees} %

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{} %
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} %

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
  \bigskip
  \begin{tikzpicture}[ %
    blue/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=blue!20}, %
    blue2/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=blue!20,text width=2.9cm,text centered,grow=south}, %
    red/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=red!20,text width=2.3cm,text centered}, %
    ] %
    \footnotesize \node [blue] {Here's a basic question for our subject} %
    [edge from parent fork down] %
    [sibling distance=2cm] %
    child {node[red,anchor=east] {Answer 1} %
      [sibling distance=0.3cm] %
      child {node[blue2,anchor=east] {Answer 1 may lead to} %
        child {node[red,anchor=south] {Theory A}} %
      } %
      child {node[blue2,anchor=west] {Answer 1 may also lead to} %
        child {node[red,anchor=south] {Theory B}} %
      }} %
    child{node[red,anchor=west] {Answer 2} %
      child {node[blue2,anchor=west] {Answer 2 leads to another question} %
        [sibling distance=5.5cm] %
        child {node[red,anchor=west]{Answer 3} %
          [sibling distance=0.8cm] %
          child {node[red,anchor=east]{Theory C}} %
          child {node[red,anchor=west]{Theory D}} %
        } %
        child {node[red,anchor=east]{Answer 4}}}}; %
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I also have a "Theory E" and "Theory F" that go under "Answer 4".  I would like to increase the vertical space under "Answer 2 leads to another question" and "Answer 3" and "Answer 4"; push "Answer 3" to the left to be under the branch of "Answer 1" to make space for the children of "Answer 4".  I can't figure out how to do that.

[image]

**EDIT:** Maybe I should emphasize that I'm specifically looking for a solution that moves "Answer 3" and its children **under** "Theory A"/"Theory B" so that it lines up vertically with "Answer 1". Then I could have "Answer 4" directly under "Answer 2 leads to another question" and add "Theory E" and "Theory F" as its children.  I can't add any horizontal space to the slide (it has fixed dimensions) and I can't make the font any smaller, because I want people to be able to read it (it's already \footnotesize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the forest package is simple:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{solution with the \texttt{forest} package}
\begin{center} 
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={          % style of nodes in the tree
         font = \sffamily\scriptsize\linespread{0.8}\selectfont,
        align = center,%   text centered,
         fill = red!20, draw,
                        % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
         grow = south,
    forked edge,        % for forked edge
        s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
        l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
     fork sep = 4mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
               }% end for tree
[Here's a basic question for our subject, fill=blue!20
    [Answer 1
        [Answer 1\\ may lead to, fill=blue!20
            [Theory A]
        ]
         [Answer 1 may\\ also lead to, fill=blue!20
            [Theory B]
        ]
    ]
    [Answer 2
        [Answer 2 leads to\\ another question, fill=blue!20
            [Answer 3
                [Theory C]
                [Theory D]
            ]
            [Answer 4
                [Theory E]
                [Theory F]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
  \end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- used are only elementary function of `forest`
- that tree can be fit to frame size the used font size is reduced to `\small`. with this is not need to push branches under node *Answer 2 leads to\ another question* under left branches. by this the tree is more clear to my opinion)
- minimal nodes size aren't defined, their sizes are left to adoption to their content size
- it is possible to add more sophisticated possibility of `forest` for coloring nodes regarding to their position in the three. however i estimate that this would make code less clear for start of `forest` use

**addendum:**
if i correctly understood edit of your question, than you looking for the following tree:

[image]

code for this frame is:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{solution with the \texttt{forest} package}
\begin{center}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={draw, 
             font = \sffamily\small\linespread{0.8}\selectfont,
             fill = red!20,
            align = center,
    % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
             grow = south,
        forked edge,        % for forked edge
            s sep = 4mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 6mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = 3mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
              }
[Here's a basic question for our subject, fill=blue!20
    [Answer 1, 
        [Answer 1\\ may lead to, fill=blue!20
            [Theory A]
            [,phantom
                [Answer 3, no edge,
                 tier=answer, name=answ3
                    [Theory C]
                    [Theory D]
                ]
            ]
            [Theory B]
        ]
     ]
    [Answer 2
        [Answer 2 leads to\\ another question, fill=blue!20,
         s sep+=12mm 
            [,coordinate,name=answ2]
            [,coordinate
                [Answer 4,tier=answer
                    [Theory E]
                    [Theory F]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
    \draw (answ2) |- ([yshift=2.5mm] answ3.north) -- (answ3);
\end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Thanks for your addition.  After playing around with it, I found it was indeed easy to achieve what I wanted.  I did not know about the forest package before.

Comment: @GrB, you are welcome!. `forest` is very powerful package. i still learning  it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could move the children using `[level distance=XXcm]` and `[sibling distance=XXcm]`.

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer} %
\usepackage{tikz} %
\usetikzlibrary{trees} %

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{} %
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} %

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
  \bigskip
  \begin{tikzpicture}[ %
    blue/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=blue!20}, %
    blue2/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=blue!20,text width=2.9cm,text centered,grow=south}, %
    red/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=red!20,text width=2.3cm,text centered}, %
    ] %
    \footnotesize \node [blue] {Here's a basic question for our subject} %
    [edge from parent fork down] %
    [sibling distance=2cm] %
    child {node[red,anchor=east] {Answer 1} %
      [sibling distance=0.3cm] %
      child {node[blue2,anchor=east] {Answer 1 may lead to} %
        child {node[red,anchor=south] {Theory A}} %
      } %
      child {node[blue2,anchor=west] {Answer 1 may also lead to} %
        child {node[red,anchor=south] {Theory B}} %
      }} %
    child{node[red,anchor=west] {Answer 2} %
      child{node[blue2,anchor=west] {Answer 2 leads to another question} %
        [sibling distance=8cm] %
        child[level distance=2cm,sibling distance=8cm]{node[red,anchor=west]{Answer 3} %
          [sibling distance=0.8cm] %
          child[level distance=2cm]{node[red,anchor=east]{Theory C}} %
          child[level distance=2cm]{node[red,anchor=west]{Theory D}} %
        } %
        child[level distance=2cm]{node[red,anchor=east]{Answer 4}}}}; %
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

***Hint:*** I added `[aspectratio=169]` to the document class, for a wider screen.

[image]

Comment: This will not work for me.  It's a beamer slide, so I can't change the aspect ratio (that would mess up the formating of the other slides).  That's why I would like to use the space below "Theory A" and "Theory B" for the "Answer 3" branch.  I'm constrained by beamer here.  The same applies to Zarko's answer below.